# Upload, Insert, Retrieve and Display Image using JPA JSF MySql

Tags: java, mysql, image, jsf, jpa-2.0

I am asking this question and I intend to answer the question for others to learn. Its pretty simple and straight forward. I Hope it helps.

This is it

Create your entity for example customer with your blob field

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Lob
    private byte[] logo;


//setter and getter required
```

Create a session Bean to help communicate with the entity for example

```
@Stateless
public class CustomerService {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ImageTestPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void persist(Object object) {
        em.persist(object);
    }


    public List<Customer> customerList(){
       return em.createNamedQuery(stat).getResultList();
    }

    public byte[] loadImage(int id){
        return em.find(Customer.class, id).getLogo();
    }

}
```

Create your managedBean. Take note of the  `private UploadedFile uploadedFile;` its from the

> org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.UploadedFile; which i will explain later.

```
public class CustomerManager {
    @EJB
    private CustomerService customerService;
    private Customer customer = new Customer();
    private List<Customer> list;
    private DataModel<Customer> dataModel;
    private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

    public CustomerManager() {
    }
    public void createCustomer() throws IOException{
        customer.setId(0);
         byte[] file = uploadedFile.getBytes();
         customer.setLogo(file);
         customerService.persist(customer);
    }

    public void loadTable(){
         dataModel = new ListDataModel<Customer>();
        dataModel.setWrappedData(customerService.findStatus(customer));
    } 

    public String view(){
        customer = dataModel.getRowData();
        return "view.xhtml";
    }
//setter and getter for all
//use the loadTable method to load your model table
```

Create the servlet class. Its the most important to display your image. Take note of the following, they are the most important

```
@WebServlet(name = "ImageServlet", urlPatterns = {"/ImageServlet"})
```

this is to avoid web.xml editing, it easier if you ask me. just get the url of the file.

```
int id =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        byte[] image = customerService.loadImage(id);

        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(image);
        outputStream.close();
```

The above line seems to be self explanatory.
Dont worry much about the `id` it will be use to reference the image in the xhtml later.

so the full servlet look more like this

```
@WebServlet(name = "ImageServlet", urlPatterns = {"/ImageServlet"})
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @EJB
    private CustomerService customerService;


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        int id =Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        byte[] image = customerService.loadImage(id);

        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        outputStream.write(image);
        outputStream.close();
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP
     * <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

This is the create xhtml that uploads and save image bytes to the db

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">
    <h:head>
        <title> Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                username :<h:inputText value="#{customerManager.customer.username}"/>
                Status :<h:inputText value="#{customerManager.customer.status}"/>
                <h:outputLabel for="file" value="Select file" />
                <t:inputFileUpload id="file" value="#{customerManager.uploadedFile}" required="true" />
                    <h:message for="file" style="color: red;" />

                    <h:commandButton value="Create" action="#{customerManager.createCustomer()}"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is the list page to list your data in the db. it is attached with a commandlink that takes you to the the view page

```
<h:dataTable value="#{customerManager.dataModel}" var="list">
            <h:column>
                #{list.id}
            </h:column>

            <h:column>
                <h:commandLink value="#{list.username}" action="#{customerManager.view}"  />

            </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
```

In conclusion, I wish this helps someone someday. And I wish someone takes time to solve problems in the most simple way because I still have plenty unanswered questions, but  will keep on reading when i'll get it right I will share it in the most simple way for people like me.
For the `upload` earlier mention please your will need to download to tomahawk library. I think people like balusc blog about it. He just made it look complex than it should be. just pick things you need from the blog and use it. He is a good guy no dispute about that. cheers

Comment: I see lots of code, but no question to be answered.

Comment: if you want to share knowlede you should ask a question, like "How can I upload, insert, retrieve and Display images using JPA, JSF and MySql? and then answer that question yourself, not add a tutorial inside a question..

Comment: At the time i was typing this, i was ask to wait for eight hours and i couldn't wait that long so i opt for this option. Some one in need will definitely find it someday and it will be of help no matter where it is. Besides, i have found most of my answer in questions.